# Correr aplicacion django en xampp server

Tags: django

Llevo dias tratando de correr una aplicacion hecha en django en un servidor apache, y no logro hacerlo, he probado con el mod_wsgi y con mod_django.dll y con ambas el servidor apache se crachea, alguna solucion viable? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu estructura de directorios, y la configuración de apache?

Comment: ya hermano gracias despues de romperme la cabeza logre montar usando bitnami django